# Где меняется $items?

Tags: php

Почему массив $items после обработки в цикле добавляет к своим элементам  subcategories я же работаю с масcивом $pointers?

$pointers = array();

```
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) 
    {
        if(isset($item->perent_external_id))
        {
            if(isset($pointers[$item->perent_external_id]))
            {
                $pointers[$item->external_id] = $item;
                $pointers[$item->perent_external_id]->subcategories[] = $items[$item->external_id];
                unset($items[$key]);
            }
        }
        else
            $pointers[$item->external_id] = $item;
    }
    print_r($items);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ммм... по ходу $item у тебя объект, а объекты копируются по ссылке. Сначала ты пишешь эту строчку

```
* $pointers[$item->external_id] = $item;
```

то есть копируешь объект $item в массив $pointers, а потом

```
$pointers[$item->perent_external_id]->subcategories[] = $items[$item->external_id]
```

присваиваешь подкатегорию как бы элементу массива $pointers, но из-за первой (*) строчки этот элемент указывает на объект $item, так как объекты копируются по ссылке и в итоге получается, что у объектов из массива $items есть подкатегории. Я так понимаю происходящее.